# When is the "Resourceful" trait active?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I have a monster that has the *Resourceful* trait, but when is it active?  Is it active when it's in my pack or only when I'm using it during the final kill?

Answer (score 2):

The *Resourceful* trait doesn't instill any innate bonuses: it just indicates the monster can learn certain passives that increase rewards (e.g., *Item Scavenger* and *Item Collector*).

Those passives, however, are active as long as the monster is in your paradigm pack: you don't need to use any of the paradigms the monster is in or have the monster active during the final blow.